# View Resets to Default When Keyboard is First Brought Up (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

Good morning/evening everyone. I am trying to make it so when the keyboard shows up, the text field and the entire view moves up. I am using some `NSNotificationCenter` code to find it the keyboard is on the screen (`UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`).

This method is called with no problems, and then it changes the view correctly. But the FIRST time and only the FIRST time it is called, the view resets to the default value, not the new value.

Then, the second, third, etc. times, it works perfectly. How can I fix this?

**ViewDidLoad**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardOnScreen:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardOffScreen:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

**Methods:**

```
-(void)keyboardOnScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{



    NSDictionary *info  = notification.userInfo;
    NSValue      *value = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    CGRect rawFrame      = [value CGRectValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:rawFrame fromView:nil];

    double y = keyboardFrame.size.height;


    if (y == 0) {

        NSLog(@"prevented error!");


    } else {

    NSLog(@"%f", y);


    CGRect frame = [input frame];



    double nonorigil = origianltexty - y;
    frame.origin.x = originaltextx;
    frame.origin.y = nonorigil;


    [input setFrame:frame];



    CGRect fra = [scrollView frame];


    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    fra.size.height = (screenHeight - y) - 60;



    [scrollView setFrame:fra];

    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];

    }


}

-(void) keyboardOffScreen: (NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"keyboard went away");

}
```

**When "Send" button is pressed...**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

   input.text = @"";

    CGRect frame = [input frame];

    frame.origin.x = originaltextx;
    frame.origin.y = origianltexty;

    [input setFrame:frame];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: How did you 'rule out' your code? Yes. Post code. For example: What do you do when that notification is received? What do you do when keyboard dismisses, etc.... all of it. Otherwise, we're just telling you how to do it without knowing what you've tried or that our specific answers will work.

Comment: @ChrisSlowik I added it. I see where you are coming from. Thanks for the help and time!

Comment: You don't need to convertRect on that keyboard frame to get the height. Will try and run this code in a minute and see what helps.

Comment: is the input within the scroll view? why do you set the input frame and then adjust the scrollview?

Comment: @ChrisSlowik Can you please explain? n00b. I get the keyboard frame height because sizes can vary, and I want to make it automatically format. Is there a better way? Please give code examples. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisSlowik I completely removed the `convertRect` and used the first line primarily. There was no difference in performance, it acted the same way.

Comment: Oh, yea I was just saying that it didn't need to be converted - it's already the frame you need when you retrieve it. Anyway, did you see my other question about your layout? Just curious how your thing is structured because im noticing you changed the scrollview AND the text field.

Comment: @ChrisSlowik The input is not inside the scroll view. I found it a lot more simple to leave it out of there.

Comment: Ok, is there anything else in the scrollview, or are you just moving around a label?

Comment: @ChrisSlowik I am just moving around a bunch of labels inside the scrollview. Otherwise, there is nothing in there.

Comment: @ChrisSlowik This is really getting weird. I made it `NSLog@"setting a frame"` whenever an input frame is changed. When the first text input happens, it does not `NSLog` this message. UGH!

Comment: Thats odd.. Are yousaying that `keyboardOnScreen:` doesn't get called? Or just that the frame doesn't change?

Comment: How did you fix this man?I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i finnaly overcome this by using auto layout and changing constraints constant, not frame size or position in notification delegates functions, like this:

P.S. I'm not using scrollview just simple move view up, but it should work similar

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if !keyboardIsShown{
            self.infoViewTopConstraint.constant -= keyboardSize.height
            self.infoViewBottomConstraint.constant += keyboardSize.height
            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            keyboardIsShown = true
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if keyboardIsShown {
        self.infoViewTopConstraint.constant += keyboardSize.height
        self.infoViewBottomConstraint.constant -= keyboardSize.height
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        keyboardIsShown = false
    }
}
```